# Pass PHP variable to server

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

So I have this variable of `$date = array($year,$month);` inside a couple of nested `foreach` statements. I have a link that when pressed should pass the `$date` variable over to my functions.php for me to play around with.

I'm using wordpress and so far I understand the link has to work something like this:

```
$link = admin_url('admin-ajax.php?[$date variable needs to go here]&post_id='.$post->ID.'&nonce='.$nonce);
```

Basically my question is how exactly does the link above need to be formatted to send my variable? Also, on the server side, how best to receive that variable?

Comment: is your `$date` variable different than your `$nonce` variable? they're both variables, they're sent the same way

Comment: Try [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.http-build-query.php)

Comment: @Bora The same in english : [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

Comment: @tymeJV this has nothing to do with server side. He's correctly trying to do this the only problem is that he wants to output an array.

Comment: @STTLCU Ah, I thought post_id and nonce were some predefined names, as I saw this link in an example I'm following. So if they're not could I just say `&my_date='.$date'` and that will send the data?

Comment: @Christoph is there a problem with sending over arrays?

Comment: @Kyle Joseph no you simply have to transform them to a string before outputting them than convert them back (e.g. using http_build_query or json_encode() + json_decode()). Don't forget to use urlencode if your forwarding data to a link.

Comment: @Christoph Sweet, I get it now. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can't send arrays directly through GET requests (GET requests are the ones with the parameters visible in the url, in layman terms)

therefore, you should do the following:

```
$date = "$year-$month"; //example: 2013-09
$link = admin_url('admin-ajax.php?my_date='.$date.'&post_id='.$post->ID.'&nonce='.$nonce);
```

breaking the url down to the components, in layman terms:

1. everything before the `?` is the server address and the page that needs to be served
2. everything after is the so-called "querystring", which is a sequence of pairs (`A=B`) separated by ampersands `&`.

so, a URL that looks like this

```
www.example.com/dynamic_page.php?A=B&C=D&E=F
```

means:

visit www.example.com, fetch the page named "dynamic_page.php" and use the value B for the variable A, the value D for the variable C and the value F for the variable E.

Comment: Thank you very much :) Well explained.